# using Android Google Maps API to display a Heat Map layer

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap, android-mapview

I am doing a project in Android, where I have given a list of Geography Points (lat, lng) and each point has an associated Altitude(height) value with it.

My task is to create a Heat Map of the given map with varying colors depending on the points altitude value.

Does someone know of any existing library for doing the same. Or, it would also be very helpful to me if anyone can give pointers on how it cam be implemented. My only constraint is that it should work in Android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

[mapex](http://code.google.com/p/mapex/), for example. Or [this post](http://blog.furiousbob.com/2011/05/12/heating-up-my-new-xoom-tablet/).

Comment: thanks @a.ch. I tried mapex and it giving me an exception for Android API 10. Ill will try your other recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

The question is old but Google launched recently the new *Google Maps Android API Utility Library* allowing to create easily heatmaps. Take a look the [BlogPost](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2014/02/marker-clustering-and-heatmaps-new.html) and the [Google Maps V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/heatmap) documentation.

Also, the source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) with some sample code available.