# Generate heat map layer using google map api v2 for android

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I want to plot heat map on  android phone based on the signal strength in a area. i am able to get google map using android map api v2 . but i am not getting any idea  how to plot heatmap on it . I have gone through
[using Android Google Maps API to display a Heat Map layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902688/using-android-google-maps-api-to-display-a-heat-map-layer) but the link to mapex here didn't help much . Please  help

Comment: I assume that you have the data and just can't plot it as a heat map. What doesn't work?

Comment: What i am looking for is an example on how to plot the heat map layer dynamically  or some kind of documentation to which i could refer to make things work ;I have done it on browser ; want to port my application to android. i have Lat , Lng data with signal strength in a file .

Comment: what's wrong with this? http://blog.furiousbob.com/2011/05/12/heating-up-my-new-xoom-tablet/ found through your link.

Comment: how do i get hold of bitmap object for the FragmentActivity . AND how do i use HeatView class

Answer (score 2):

This is just a thought, but have you thought of using Circles built in V2 maps.. This may sound weird but it may suit your needs...

I would assume each point has a specific radius that you could set and then you could use a color with some transparency that when close to other points would overlap each other making the color darker in areas of higher point concentration and lighter in areas of less concentration.  Of course this would only work if you were looking to do this with one color and different shades of that color. For example:

```
// Instantiates a new CircleOptions object and defines the center and radius
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(37.4, -122.1))
    .radius(10)); // In meters
    .fillColor(0x1AFF0000)//90% transparent red
    .strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)//dont show the border to the circle
// Get back the mutable Circle
Circle circle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

And if you were to do this and then add it again at the same point but with a radius of 20, you would get an output like the attached image which would allow you to fade from a specific point as it gets further away. It would be as simple as throwing all your points in a for loop and adding the circles to the map in the loop.  This may not be what your looking for but may help someone!  [image: ExampleMap]